# Как в Windows 10 сделать так, чтобы USB флеш-накопители не надо было отключать отдельной командой?

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10, usb

Как известно, в Windows, когда завершаешь операции с  USB флеш-накопителем, его надо отключить отдельной командой. После этой команды появляется сообщение "теперь накопитель ХХХ можно удалить".

Надоело мне каждый раз отключать USB флеш-накопители отдельной командой. Помнится мне, что когда в ходу были дискеты, то для них не было никакой отдельной команды для отключения. Конец операции копирования на дискету означал, что дискету можно вынимать.

Вопрос:

Как в Windows 10 сделать так, чтобы не надо было отключать USB флеш-накопители отдельной командой? Хочу, чтобы как при работе с дискетами, окончание операции копирования (чтения или записи) означало, что USB флеш-накопитель можно вынимать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Втыкаем флешку.
2. Идем в Диспетчер устройств, находим в нем флешку, правый клик - Свойства.
3. Во второй вкладке активируем верхнюю опцию "Быстрое удаление".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Важно: окончание операции записи/копирования определяется не исчезновением индикатора процесса копирования, а тем, что на флешке перестал мигать светодиод.

*PS. Это в Вин7. Если в Вин10 не так, то удалю ответ.*

Comment: Менеджер устройств это диспетчер устройств?

Comment: Совершенно верно.

Comment: В Вин-10 так же как в Вин-7. Более того, по умолчанию стоит птичка "не кэшировать".

Comment: [а тем, что на флешке перестал мигать светодиод] Это не критерий. У меня USB-диск трансенд на 2 гига. У него светодиод горит всегда, пока он подключен к компу. Нужно именно чтобы программно запись не кэшировалась и окончание записи в винде означало, что физически запись закончена на носителе.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про флешки или про диски?

Comment: "Более того, по умолчанию стоит птичка "не кэшировать"  - значит можно вытаскивать сразу после копирования.

Comment: [Вы спрашиваете про флешки или про диски?] И про флешки и про диски. Какая винде (да и мне) разница что там воткнуто?

Comment: В вопросе про флешки, ответ про флешки. Какая вам разница известно только вам, а винде разница есть - у флешек есть в контекстном меню опция "Извлечь", а у дисков нет.

Comment: [ у флешек есть в контекстном меню опция "Извлечь", а у дисков нет.] Это переносной USB-диск. У него тоже есть опция "извлечь".

Comment: И да, какие есть гарантии, что при следующем втыкании другой или той же самой флешки там будет стоять "не кэшировать запись"?

Comment: В Вин7 у внешних дисков такой опции нет.